# Validate a related entity, at least one

Tags: symfony

I have two entities, "Page" and "Sections". The entity "Page" have a oneToMany Relation to entity "Section".

I create a form with collection of pages and sections. I would like to validate that a page have at least one section.

I try this in my validation yml file.

```
App\MyBundle\Entity\Page:
    properties:
        sections:
            - Valid: ~
```

Exists any constraint which can i use to handle this issue? Or must i write a own validator for this issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to see that your Page has at least one `Section` then you have to see if the section `Collection` is greater than 0.

```
App\MyBundle\Entity\Page:
    properties:
        sections:
            - Count: { min: 1, minMessage: "You need to have at least one Section" }
```

If you want to see if your Section objects are valid also then you need to setup a validation policy for your Section entity and to the PageType form set `cascade_validation => true` Like:

```
App\MyBundle\Entity\Section:
        properties:
            name:
                - NotBlank
```

And your FormType

```
    /**
     * @param OptionsResolverInterface $resolver
     */
    public function setDefaultOptions(OptionsResolverInterface $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults(array(
            'data_class' => 'App\MyBundle\Entity\Page',
            'cascade_validation' => true,
        ));
    }
```